# Accessing box.com excel spreadsheet through google Chrome. PopUp Plugin blocker

Tags: google-chrome, excel, plugins, box, vba

I am trying to automate opening up a spreadsheet from box.com through a button on excel.  The code executes which is below, however when the code tries to press the "box edit" button(little pencil graphic) Google Chrome blocks "Box Edit" from opening the spreadsheet.  I have tried the normal course of getting rid of the pop up blocker ie "Always allow popups from this site" "entering box.com under settings in chrome".  Outside of the code when I manually pull box it reads that box.com is allowed, but for some reason when the code executes it's like it is opening up a new chrome with original settings, therefore blocking the plugin.  I apologize in advance for sendkeys, not well versed with selenium add-in for excel.  Please help, literally the code executes as it is supposed to, but the popup blocker won't allow the spreadsheet to download.  THANK YOU!

```
Sub openChrome()
Dim selenium As New SeleniumWrapper.WebDriver
Dim GC As Object
Dim intRowRowPosition As Integer
Dim keys As New SeleniumWrapper.keys

selenium.Start "chrome", "https://box.com/files/0/f/*********"
selenium.setTimeout ("120000")
selenium.setImplicitWait (5000)

selenium.Open ""
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"))
SendKeys "emailaddress", True
Application.SendKeys "{Tab}"
DoEvents
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"))
SendKeys "password", True
Application.SendKeys "{Return}"
DoEvents
Application.SendKeys ("{NUMLOCK}")
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))

selenium.clickAndWait "id=preview_header_edit_btn"
End Sub
```

Comment: Just a heads up.  I figured out a work around.  I wrote a macro to enable box.com plugin prior to going to grab my file from box.com.  An extra layer, but it'll work for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a workaround and added to my code. (below)

```
selenium.Start "chrome", "Chrome://plugins"
selenium.setTimeout ("120000")
selenium.setImplicitWait (5000)
selenium.Open ""
selenium.clickAndWait "id=npBoxEdit.dll-always-allowed"
Application.SendKeys "^l", True
DoEvents
Application.SendKeys "https://box.com/files/0/f/"
Application.SendKeys "{Return}"
```